# Python Script won't connect using Proxy Settings, Pycharm appears to be connected

Tags: python, proxy, pycharm

I'm trying to execute a few simple Python scripts to retrieve information from the internet, unfortunately I'm behind a Corporate Proxy which makes this somewhat Tricky. So far I have installed CNTLM and configured it to work with Pycharm 1.4.  I have configured both such that when I 'Check Connection' to www.google.com in pycharm using my manual proxy settings it returns 'Connection Successful'.

However when I try and simple scripts from pycharm, they all seem to timeout. Any advice? By way of code example, this will return a 503 response. Thanks!

```
import requests
URL = "http://google.com"
try:
    response = requests.get(URL)
    print response
except Exception as e:
    print "Something went wrong:"
    print e
```